# Batch file help: created new folder from PDF file name, need to transfer another file into the new folder that has different name

Tags: batch-file, copy, dos

I'm working on a batch file that creates a new folder using an existing PDF file name, and then copies the PDF file as well an "STP" file into the new folder. Having issues copying "STP" files that have a slightly different name into the newly created folder w/PDF name.

Files: File001.pdf, File001.stp, File002.pdf, File002_RA_V9.stp
My script creates a folder named after the PDF file, and then transfers a copy of the PDF and the corresponding STP file into the new folder...but I can't figure out a way to copy the File002_RA_V9.stp into the File002 folder.

Here's my script:

`@ECHO OFF
SET /P todir=Please drap and drop destination directory:
for /f %%f in ('dir *.pdf /b') do md %todir%\%%~nf & xcopy %%f %todir%\%%~nf
for /f %%f in ('dir *.stp /b') do xcopy %%f %todir%\%%~nf`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f %%f in ('dir *.pdf /b') do md %todir%\%%~nf & xcopy %%f %todir%\%%~nf\&xcopy %%~nf*.stp %todir%\%%~nf\
```

or

```
for /f %%f in ('dir *.pdf /b') do md %todir%\%%~nf & xcopy %%f %todir%\%%~nf&xcopy %%~nf*.stp %todir%\%%~nf\%%~nf.stp
```

if you want to remove the "junk" after `file002`

(untested)

Comment: The first bit of code worked perfectly.
Thanks for your help @Magoo!